# removing data from join using information in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have created a JOIN to display the data I need to allow the user to see all the stories available for them to choose.

```
$sql = ("
SELECT * 
  FROM guest
     , story 
 WHERE guest.userid = story.userid 
   AND guest.userid = $_SESSION[id] 
 ORDER 
    BY story.st_name  
");
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

echo "<table class='p'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='z'>Story Name</td>";
echo "<td class='z'>Email</td>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$st_name    = $row['st_name'];
$email      = $row['email'];
$st_id      = $row['st_id'];
$g_id       = $row['g_id'];
$first_name = $row['first_name'];
$last_name  = $row['last_name'];

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='b'>".$st_name."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' class='checkboxes' value='$row[st_id],$row[g_id],$row[first_name],$row[last_name],$row[st_name]' >".$email."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

This data then can be saved into a database table. All this works fine. However when they call the page again the same data shows up again and if they select the same data it will be repeated in the table.

This statement shows the data in the table that was saved.

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM gs WHERE id = $_SESSION[id] ");
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$firstname     = $row['first_name'];
$lastname      = $row['last_name'];
$storyname     = $row['story_name'];
$stid          = $row['st_id'];
$storyname     = $row['story_name'];
```

Some how I would like to create in the original SELECT statement a way to test and see if this data exists and then not show it. But I am not able to figure out such a statement.

Comment: Use GET-after-POST to avoid the form-submit reload.

Comment: This is my first PHP project, I understand both GET and POST but I am lacking in understanding as to how this will solve my issue, sorry

Comment: After you receive the POST request, redirect the user to the same page again.. this will cause the browser to "forget" the last request and if the user presses F5, it won't ask to resubmit the form once again